lsp-solidity doesn't recognize `node_modules` dependencies
I can't seem to get the lsp server for solidity to recognize the dependencies coming from node_modules.

Rough cut-out of the configuration I use for Solidity:
;; Enable Solidity mode for .sol files
(require 'solidity-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sol$" . solidity-mode))

;; Flycheck configuration for Solidity
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'solidity-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)

;; Company mode configuration
(require 'company)
(require 'company-solidity)

;; Paredit mode configuration
(require 'paredit)
(add-hook 'solidity-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)

;; LSP mode configuration
(require 'lsp-mode)
(add-hook 'solidity-mode-hook #'lsp)

;; LSP UI for better user interface
(require 'lsp-ui)
(add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook 'lsp-ui-mode)

;; Local variables
(defun my-solidity-mode-setup ()
  "Custom configurations for Solidity mode."
  (setq-local company-backends '((company-dabbrev-code)))
  (setq-local flycheck-solidity-solc-addstd-contracts t)

  (setq solidity-flycheck-solc-checker-active t)
  (setq solidity-flycheck-chaining-error-level t)
  (setq solidity-flycheck-use-project t)

  ;; to find npm
  (setq exec-path (append exec-path '("~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin")))
  (setq solidity-solc-path "/usr/local/bin/solc")
  (setq solidity-solium-path "/home/filip/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/solium")

  ;; Whitespace cleanup on save
  (setq whitespace-style '(face trailing tabs spaces))
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'whitespace-cleanup nil t)

  )

(add-hook 'solidity-mode-hook 'my-solidity-mode-setup)

(setq flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(save mode-enabled))


Although interesting enough @openzeppelin is recognized (navigation also works), so something is injecting the remapping. Remapping are supposed to be taken from the foundry.toml, and this is what they look like:
remappings = [
    'ds-test/=node_modules/@layerzerolabs/toolbox-foundry/lib/ds-test',
    'forge-std/=node_modules/@layerzerolabs/toolbox-foundry/lib/forge-std',
    '@layerzerolabs/=node_modules/@layerzerolabs/',
    '@openzeppelin/=node_modules/@openzeppelin/',
]



@nomicfoundation/solidity-language-server v0.8.5
solidity-mode-20230628.1637
solidity-flycheck-20221024.220

